# unable to load php to JSON.stringify () issues

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I am trying to get data from php to json.stringify but i am new with this code and unable to understand and work with JSON.stringify. is there any possible way to get such data because i have same data stored in database and assign it into JSON.stringify

This code is working perfectly but i want to fetch these values from database using ajax or another way,
Here is code below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   store('spoitems', JSON.stringify(
    {"1":{
        "id":"1",
        "item_id":"1",
        "label":"Minion Hi (TOY01)",
        "row":{
            "id":"1",
            "code":"TOY01",
            "name":"Minion Hi",
            "category_id":"1",
            "price":"15.0000",
            "image":"6988655f95602f9394f9315165f920fe.png",
            "tax":"0",
            "cost":"10.0000",
            "tax_method":"0",
            "quantity":"4.0000",
            "barcode_symbology":"code39",
            "type":"standard",
            "details":"A toy for children aged 2 - 6",
            "alert_quantity":"0.0000",
            "store_price":"0.0000",
            "qty":"10.0000"
            }},
    "2":{
        "id":"2",
        "item_id":"2",
        "label":"Minion Banana (TOY02)",
        "row":{
            "id":"2",
            "code":"TOY02",
            "name":"Minion Banana",
            "category_id":"1",
            "price":"15.0000",
            "image":"213c9e007090ca3fc93889817ada3115.png",
            "tax":"0",
            "cost":"10.0000",
            "tax_method":"0",
            "quantity":"4.0000",
            "barcode_symbology":"code39",
            "type":"standard",
            "details":"A toy for children aged 2 - 6",
            "alert_quantity":"0.0000",
            "store_price":"0.0000",
            "qty":"10.0000"
    }}}));
});
```

Comment: Show the version where you tried to use Ajax to fetch the data. It's hard to understand what specific issue you are facing

Comment: P.s. if you are downloading data as JSON from the PHP server then it is already stringified...